# How do I use Google Groups to control access to a Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-groups

I would like to set up a Calendar that only people who are a member of a specific Group can access.  As people are added to the Group they get access to the Calendar.  If they leave the Group, they lose access to the Calendar.

Is this possible?

Some of the help implies that it is, but I don't see any clear instructions.  If I need to access the Calendar through Google Apps to do it, that's fine (though I have no clue how to do that).

A related but different question: [Can I share Google Calendars with Google Groups?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/can-i-share-google-calendars-with-google-groups)

Answer (score 1):

From the share settings of a particular calendar, add your mygroup@googlegroups.com emailaddress to the email field.